# Why are free objects related to tensors important?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, soft-question, multilinear-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be an $R$-module.

Then, we can construct the tensor algebra $T(M):=\oplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} M^{\otimes n}$ which is likely a free object. That is, for any $R$-algebra $A$ and an $R$-module morphism $\phi:M\rightarrow A$, $\phi$ can be uniquely extended to an $R$-algebra morphism from $T(M)$ to $A$.

Similarly, we can construct the symmetric algebra $S(M)$ and the exterior algebra $\bigwedge(M)$, and they have universal mapping properties. Moreover, $S^n(M)$ and $\bigwedge^n(N)$ have universal properties too.

Unlike I know free groups are directly related to van kampen theorem (hence it is extremely important to calculate fundamental groups), I don't get why I should learn symmmetric and exterior algebras. Especially, symmetric algebra.

Would someone sketch (with some details) how they are used? Especially how they are used in differential geometry?

Of course I have read wikipedia article and I know that exterior algebra can be used to calculate determinants and is a generalization of cross product and etc. However, I don't get how exactly so..

Comment: The natural context for many questions of differential geometry  is *exterior  derivative* (differential forms, *Green-Riemann* theorem, *Stokes* theorem, &c). In multilinear algebra, you have an intrinsic (independent of any basis) definition of the determinant, among other things.